# Spring 5, get info from LDAP (AD)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to make a controller that receives an email and fetches information from that user in an Active Directory returning it as json.
I'm having a hard time finding useful material because everything I find is trying to teach authentication through WebSecurity annotation...
I couldn't care less about the authentication, I only want Spring to get info and nothing else.

Can anybody tell me how to get out from this to what I need?

```
@Bean
public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(LDAP_DOMAIN, LDAP_URL, LDAP_ROOT_DN);
    provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    provider.setSearchFilter(LDAP_FILTER);
    return provider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and().formLogin();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LdapTemplate` if you want to just get information. You can find information [spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/1.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/basic.html) . Besides, this [tutorial](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-spring-ldap-advanced-ldap-queries-example/) has lots of ldap query examples with `LdapTemplate`